# Change database column name and its type without losing data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to change name and type of column from `BIT(1)` to `INT(1)`.

I am using MySQL Workbench.

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD new_column_name INT(1)

update table_name
set new_column_name = convert(INT(1), old_column_name)

ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN old_column_name
```

But I am getting this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT(1), old_column_name)'
```

Comment: Are you aware that `INT(1)` does ***not*** limit the values to just one digit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD new_column INT(1);

update table_name
  set new_column = case when old_column then 1 else 0 end;

ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN old_column;
```

or simply use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN old_column int;
```

Comment: thanks buddy it's working.
but i want to know why i was getting that error.

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_column_name new_col_name varchar(20) not null;
```

I put varchar as an examaple. you can change to any data type you like. You can also add constraints after that.

Answer (score 2):

Try something Like this.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD new_column_name INT

update table_name
set new_column_name = convert(int,convert(varchar(1), old_column_name))
```

Comment: getting this error-->You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT, convert(VARCHAR(1), old_column_name)'

Comment: I was wrong. `convert()` is indeed a MySQL function (although pretty limited it seems)

Answer (score 2):

`INT(1)` doesn't seem to be a valid type for conversion.

Furthermore, the right syntax is `CONVERT(<element>, <type>)`.

You can find more in detail [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert).

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN creation_date TYPE timestamp USING creation_date::timestamp;
```

try this

Comment: while this can answer the question it's always better to add some explanation to the answer